# How not to link with libm using Intel C Compiler

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, icc, libm

I want to compile some very basic test code calling the log function and then printing the result on the standard output on Linux, with the Intel C Compiler. I want the code to be linked against libimf (Intel's Math Functions library) and *not* the GNU libm, so that I can be sure which `log` function is called.

So far I have managed to link with libimf.so with `-limf`, but `icc` links against libm.so with `-lm` **by default**.
I would like to avoid this. How should I proceed?

Comment: a shot in the dark, did you try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable ?

Comment: Yes, although I was not `export`-ing it. Now exporting the variable, I can link with `-limf` and `ldd` shows `libimf.so` as expected. But I'd like not to link with `-lm` by default, because now it is hard to say which `log` I am calling !

Comment: setting/exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH overwrites other libraries. suppose you have a file names libX.so in /home, and there is also a file name libX.so in /lib, after setting/exporting the env variable, the compiler will use the one in the env variable path.

Comment: The thing is, `icc` links with `lm` by default but not with `-limf`, so that `ldd` says : `libimf.so => /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.150/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libimf.so (0x00007ff36497c000)` **and** `libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff364676000)`

Comment: i was skimming through icc's manual, i found that there is an option to disable linking against standard libraries : -nodefaultlibs
http://scv.bu.edu/computation/bladecenter/manpages/icc.html #scroll down to linking options )

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene Perfect ! Could make it an answer so that I can mark it as solved? I searched the manual for some keywords but did not manage to find this option, so now using `-limf -lc` is just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107112/discussion-between-hdl-and-baroudi-safwene).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to override linking against system libraries, we should set and export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
according to the icc manual, icc links against some default libraries, to disable this behavior add the -nodefaultlibs